# Run multiple containers in AWS Fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, traefik, aws-fargate

I'm trying to run a Fargate task with multiple containers.

I would like to have one URL in my front app and to do the routing based on the path of the request. So far I can't figure what's the best way to do it.

Do I have to do it 'by hand' with different rules on the load balancer and with multiple target groups or is it possible to do the routing once the request is inside the Fargate task ? (with Traefik or Nginx for example)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Do I have to do it 'by hand' with different rules on the load
> balancer and with multiple target groups or is it possible to do the
> routing once the request is inside the Fargate task ? (with Traefik or
> Nginx for example)"

You can do either. Both methods are possible.